Docker - Nginx doesn't let me access wp-admin
I have a docker compose that runs three containers: MariaDB, WordPress and Nginx. When I do https://localhost in Firefox, I get a wordpress sample page, which is what I want. However, when I try to access https://localhost/wp-admin/, it just redirects me to the same sample page. When I try to  https://localhost/wp-login.php/ I can access the login page (even though I can't login with my credentials) and can also access https://ataboada.42.fr/wp-admin/install.php. This is my Dockerfile and nginx.conf:
FROM    debian:bullseye

EXPOSE  443

RUN     apt-get update \ 
        && apt-get install -y \
            nginx \
            openssl \
            curl \
            wget \
            telnet \
        && apt-get clean \
        && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

COPY    conf/nginx.conf /etc/nginx/nginx.conf

RUN     openssl req -x509 -nodes -days 365 -newkey rsa:2048 \
        -keyout /etc/nginx/cert.key \
        -out /etc/nginx/cert.crt \
        -subj "/C=${COUNTRY}/ST=${STATE}/L=${LOCATION}/O=${ORGANIZATION}/CN=${COMMON_NAME}"

CMD ["nginx", "-g", "daemon off;"]

user www-data;
worker_processes auto;

events {
   worker_connections 1024;
}

http {
   include mime.types;
   default_type application/octet-stream;
   sendfile on;
   keepalive_timeout 65;

   server {
       listen 443 ssl;
       listen [::]:443 ssl;

       server_name localhost;

       ssl_protocols TLSv1.2 TLSv1.3;

       ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/cert.crt;
       ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/cert.key;

       root /var/www/wordpress;
       index index.php index.html;

       location / {
           try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
       }

        location ~ \.php$ {
           fastcgi_pass wordpress:9000;
           fastcgi_index index.php;
           include fastcgi_params;
           fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME /var/www/wordpress$fastcgi_script_name;
           fastcgi_param PATH_INFO $fastcgi_path_info;
       }

        location ~* \.(jpg|jpeg|gif|css|png|js|ico|xml|svg|woff|woff2|ttf|eot)$ {
           try_files $uri =404;
       }
   }
}


what shows wp-admin/install.php ? is it the message "already installed" ? try to go to url wp-admin/index.php.

yeah, when i go to wp-admin/install.php it shows already installed, and when i go to wp-admin/index.php I can see a login page: https: //domain_name/wp-login.php?redirect_to=https%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%2Fwp-admin%2Findex.php&reauth=1

and ? your problem is solved ?

not really, because I still can't access /wp-admin/ as it is still being redirected to the sample page... and actually, even though I can access /wp-login.php/, it keeps saying that my password is incorrect, so I can't login either

the problem with the incorrect password is something else, look here : https://wordpress.org/documentation/article/reset-your-password/

well, i had an error in my environment variables, so now I can login, but still no access to wp-admin

Adding this line to my nginx.conf solved the issue:
location /wp-admin {
     try_files $uri $uri/ /wp-admin/index.php?$args;
}

